# Download Svg as png doesnt work on IE11

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

The svg d3 graph needs to be downloaded.I have used [saveSvgAsPngJpgSvg](https://github.com/akhilsahu/saveSvgAsPngJpgSvg) to initiate download .The code works fine on all other browsers expect IE11.
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/akhilsahu/Ldqkqn45/1/)

I have tried :

```js
svgAsDataUri(svg, {}, function(svg_uri) {
  render_width=1000;
  render_height=1000;
   var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
     canvas.height = render_height;
         canvas.width = render_width;
     document.body.appendChild(canvas);

  // Create an image and draw the SVG onto the canvas
    var image = new Image;
     image.onload = function() {
       canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(this, 0, 0, render_width, render_height);
     };
  image.src = svg_uri;
  setTimeout(function(){//download_in_ie(canvas, 'filename' + '.png'); 
   if (canvas.msToBlob) { //for IE
                var blob = canvas.msToBlob();
                window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, 'dicomimage.png');
            }
}, 3000);

    
   });
```

using [msSaveBlob](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh779016(v=vs.85).aspx) as suggested in the given [link](http://willkoehler.net/2014/11/07/client-side-solution-for-downloading-highcharts-charts-as-images.html)  results to securityError

How can i achieve this?

Comment: I don't think you can. Writing SVG to a blob will always taint the canvas on that browser.

Comment: @RobertLongson Is there a way to cenvert to png URI on IE11?

Comment: See my first comment. You could send all the data to a server, have the server convert it to a png and then have the server return the png.

Comment: An other solution, 100% client-side, but depending on your chart complexity, would be to parse the svg and directly use the canvas drawing methods to re-render your svg again on the canvas. This way you won't taint the canvas and be able to export it. We don't do library suggestions, and I personnaly think it has been badly written, but [canvg](https://github.com/gabelerner/canvg) can save you a few hours since it's been years its devs are working on exactly this idea. Otherwise, if you want to do it yourself, canvas drawings method are really similar to svg ones.

Comment: @Kaiido Have you tried msSaveBlob?

Comment: Well I don't remember exactly, but if it is sllowed from a tainted canvas, that would be a security bug, and otherwise, the solution I provide in the previous comment still works.

Comment: @Kaiido The problem occurs on conversion of canvas to png data uri which throws security error in IE11

Comment: Yes, I know the error, I know it arises whenever you draw an svg on the canvas with `drawImage` and I also know that MS only fixed this in Edge. However, canvg won't use `drawImage` to draw your svg on the canvas, but will parse its content and use canvas drawings method (`lineTo`, `moveTo`, `arc` etc.) to reproduce your svg, natively on the canvas. This way, your canvas won't be tainted, and all the export methods will work just fine. Now the real question : did you tried it?

Comment: Yes while converting to datauri throws Securityerror

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120511/discussion-between-kaiido-and-lucky).